# Add fields in Json Response of Posts REST API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I want to add a custom field in a response of posts, but when I add new fields after a while it is deleted from the file what I do.

The file that I modify its class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php and I add the new field in prepare_item_for_response function

I add this lines, that works well, but it's deleted after a time

```
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $base = "other";
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy->name );
            $datres = $terms ? array_values( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' ) ) : array();
            $data[ $base ] = implode(" ", $datres);
        }
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you shold not edit core files or core plugins, your changes are deleted becuase the files are updated. The right way do to it is thrugh Hooks and functions from a child theme / your own plugin.

[WP Child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

[WP Rest api custom end point docs](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/)

Comment: Oh really? I suppose this its happen...well I trying add custom endpoints. Thanks